# reacting to touch vs. click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, responsive-design, touch

I am working on a responsive web page using angular 1.5.x and am trying to determine the best way to react to touch events vs. click events.  Here is the scenario and the requirements.

I have a pie chart.  When using a mouse, hovering over a section of the pie chart shows a tooltip.  Clicking a section of the pie chart drills into another pie chart.

On touch devices, a single tap brings up the tooltip.  A double tap drills into another pie chart.

I understand that using a tooltip that appears on hover makes this complicated and it should be removed if possible.  Let's say that's not possible (as my UX designer is dead set on this interaction...)  How can I best react differently to a single click vs. a single tap.